# Angular 4+ httpClient best practice to use service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-http

Hello I would like to know how to organize my code:

**I have a simple user interface:**

```
export interface User {
Account: string;
Name: string;
EMail: string;
PictureURL: string;
Department: string;
JobTitle: string;
Initials: string;
Skype: string;
Office: string;
MobileNumber: string;
DirectLine: string;
IsChecked: boolean;
IsIDTitleOnly: boolean;
ID: string;
CreatedAt: string;
CreatedBy: this;
ModifiedAt: string;
ModifiedBy: this;}
```

**I have a simple service to get my data:**

```
  getCurrentUser(): Observable<User> {
const serviceUrl: string = environment.apiUrl + 'Users/Current';

return this.http.get(serviceUrl)
.map((res: User) => {
  return res;
});}
```

**And finally a simple component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from '../../interfaces/user';
import { UserService } from '../../services/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;


  constructor(
    private userService: UserService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCurrentUser()
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    this
      .userService
      .getCurrentUser()
      .subscribe(
     res => { console.log(res); this.user = res },
     err => { console.log(err); }
  )
  }
}
```

I do not have a class or constructor for my user should I always create a class or interface enough?

When I display my "user.Name" I have an error: "Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined" because the user did not have time to recover the data.

I would really like to know how to initialize my user properly, and to know if I need a class or not (if one day I have to create a new user).

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular's new http client error Cannot read property 'data' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949411/angulars-new-http-client-error-cannot-read-property-data-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

It is preferable to have an *interface* or a *class* (shape) which describes the object. This is the one of the main features which Typescript gives us to make our code strict typed in its level.

What about the `undefined error`, you can check your field when showing in the **markup**. Just add `?` mark after the field - `user?.Name`.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the quick reply,  i use the "?" but I can not imagine putting "?" all over... and I take the opportunity to extend my question, if I'm in the component X (/home): I get my data and i go to Component Y (/tmp) (to do something else). When i come back to X every time i need to retrieve my Data ? All the time i make "this.getCurrentUser()' ?

Comment: Yes you need. Because every time you left the component and come again, it will remove and create it again. You can use an singleton service in the high level to take and save the user data in their. And after injecting into your components, just get the saved data

Answer (score 0):

In your html use `*ngIf` like so:

```
<div *ngIf='user'> {{user.Name}}</div>
```

This would prevent the "Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined" error